# How to randomize the sql result set (column)?

Tags: mysql, random

```
   String q="insert into ChooseRandom (Qid,Question,Option1,Option2,Option3,Option4,Answer,isImage,ImageQuestion)  SELECT Qid,Question,Option1,Option2,Option3,Option4,Answer,isImage,ImageQuestion FROM  model ORDER BY RAND()";
```

I am using the above query for randomize sql result set and insert the randomized data's into new table. this works good but this query randomize the rows in table. i need to randomize the rows as well as column and insert into new table.

How can i do this can any one help me to fix this

Thanks in advance[image]

[image]

compare to image 1 and image 2 options are randomized as well as rows are randomized.

how can i achieve this

Comment: It would be interesting to understand what you are trying to do here.  Using a database in this manner does not seem like the most efficient solution for your problem.  Maybe we could brainstorm a better solution which might use use a different tool.

Comment: +1 for @Mark. Most likely you just want to first pick a random row and then display the options in a random order. No need to shuffle the actual data around in its storage.

Comment: @Mark can you suggest the query

Comment: @KVK I understand the randomization.  Do you need to pull this data out of a database and insert back in?  Your code snippet looks like Java.  It probably would be easier to pull the data out of the database and write a function in Java to randomize the data in the way you want.  Then if required, you could re-insert that randomized data into the DB.  I think that's a much better solution.  The only problem is that if the table is big enough, it will become problematic storing that data in memory for your Java process to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually my problem is i can randomize my database table data using rand() function in mysql. but i need to shuffle my column's all so.

i solve my issue but using array list in java i just add the column values to list and than i shuffle the list than i get the list item one by one the code what i used is given bellow .

```
List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();

     op1=rs.getString("Option1");
     op2=rs.getString("Option2");
     op3=rs.getString("Option3");
     op4=rs.getString("Option4");

    lst.add(op1);
    lst.add(op2);
    lst.add(op3);
    lst.add(op4);

Collections.shuffle(lst);


    op1=lst.get(0);
    op2=lst.get(1);
    op3=lst.get(2);
    op4=lst.get(3);
```

than i used this values to what ever i want.